# Passing parameter to schedule_selecter

Tags: cocos2d-x

Hey guys i am using schedule_selecter in cocos2dx project, where i am having 7 different int values. I am generating random value among these 7 values. Now i want to pass this random value to another function after some interval. I am using schedule_selecter to make call after some interval but it does not allow me to pass value. how can i do this???

ex.

int random_val = arc4random() % 7;

...

function_selected_value(int random_val)
{
....
}

i want to pass random_val to function_selected_value using schedule_selecter

thnx in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

`schedule_selecter` does not allow you to pass any data with functor. Instead you can assign value to any member variable and access there in callback function.

```
// scheduling a function with interval of 1 seconds.
float interval = 1.0f; // interval to call scheduler function. 

CCNode::schedule(schedule_selector(MyClass::scheduleFunction), interval);

void MyClass::scheduleFunction(float dt) {
    // use your random number related code here
}
```

Comment: Can you put demo code here how can i use callback function.